# Solve integral $\int\frac{2x}{e^{2x}+4}\ dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$∫\frac{2x}{e^{2x}+4}\,dx$$

I tried to transform denominator to $e^{2*x}+2^2$ to match formula:

$$∫\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\ dx =  \frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+c$$
But I have no idea what to do next

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+2x%2F%28e%5E%282x%29+%2B+4%29+dx+) gives $$\int \frac{2 x}{e^{2 x} + 4} dx = -\frac{1}{8} \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{e^{2 x}}{4}\right) + \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{x}{4} \log\left(\frac{e^{2 x}}{4} + 1\right) + C.$$

Comment: Looks too difficult

Comment: Maybe the integral is meant to be [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718527/integration-by-substitution-of-fraction-involving-e)? The only difference is the $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: I think, it should. Thank you